# Using Beanshell sampler return value in JMeter while condition

Tags: while-loop, jmeter, beanshell

[image]

I am trying to use the return value from beanshell sampler, later in the while `condition ${__javaScript(${homeState}<6)}`.

When i run and check logs, `${homeState}` is not getting replaced with the beanshell sampler homeState integer value.

Can any one suggest what's wrong going on?

however, when i check the response of beanshell sampler in view results tree, it is returing integer as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`return` keyword in Beanshell defines Beanshell sampler response data. If you need to store the value into a JMeter Variable you should replace the line `return homeState` with the following expression:

```
vars.put("homeState", String.valueOf(homeState));
```

`vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to the JMeter Variables in scope.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for comprehensive information on using Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests

Comment: Another question related to this.

Comment: another question related this. i am trying to assign a Jmeter variable to another variable in bean shell sampler using "vars.put("End", vars.get("homeEnd")); " .And, i am using ${End} variable in the throughput controller to represent percentage throughput. but, getting below error in the logs.

Comment: 2016/12/22 22:42:30 WARN  - jmeter.control.ThroughputController: Error parsing ${End} java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${End}"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)